# Cassandra Datastax BatchStatement with Lightweight Transactions

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I'm having difficulty combining BatchStatement and Lightweight Transactions using the Datastax java driver.

Consider the following:

```
String batch = 
"BEGIN BATCH " 
+ "Update mykeyspace.mytable set record_version = 102 where id = '" + id + "' if record_version = 101; 
" <additional batched statements>
+ "APPLY BATCH";

Row row = session.execute(batch).one();
if (! row.getBool("[applied]")) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Optimistic Lock Failure!");
}
```

This functions as expected and indicates whether my lightweight transaction succeeded and my batch was applied.  All is good.  However if I try the same thing using a BatchStatement, I run into a couple of problems:

-- My lightweight transaction "if" clause is ignored and the update is always applied

-- The "Row" result is null making it impossible to execute the final row.getBool("[applied]") check.

```
String update = "Update mykeyspace.mytable set record_version = ? where id = ? if record_version = ?";
PreparedStatement pStmt = getSession().prepare(update);
BatchStatement batch = new BatchStatement();
batch.add(new BoundStatement(pStmt).bind(newVersion, id, oldVersion));

Row row = session.execute(batch).one();                     <------ Row is null!
if (! row.getBool("[applied]")) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Optimistic Lock Failure!");
}
```

Am I doing this wrong?  Or is this a limitation with the datastax BatchStatement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am encountering this same issue. I opened a ticket with DataStax support yesterday and received the following answer:

> Currently Lightweight Transactions as PreparedStatements within a BATCH are not supported. This is why you are encountering this issue.
>
> There is nothing on the immediate roadmap to include this feature in Cassandra.

That suggests eliminating the PreparedStatement will workaround the issue. I'm going to try that myself, but haven't yet.

[Update]

I've been trying to work around this issue. Based on the earlier feedback, I assumed the restriction was on using a PreparedStatement for the conditional update.

I tried changing my code to not use a PreparedStatement, but that still didn't work when using a BatchStatement that contained a RegularStatement instead of a PreparedStatement.

```
BatchStatement batchStatement = new BatchStatement(); 
batchStatement.add(conditionalRegularStatement); 
session.executeQuery(batchStatement);
```

They only thing that seems to work is to do an executeQuery with a raw query string that includes the batch.

```
session.executeQuery("BEGIN BATCH " + conditionalRegularStatement.getQueryString() + " APPLY BATCH");
```

Comment: Thanks very much for running this past DataStax...though  I think their answer is extremely unfortunate.  I would consider this usecase fairly central to the use of Lightweight Transactions.

Comment: Looks like there is a bug submitted for this now:
https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-337

Answer (score 3):

### Update:

This issue is resolved in [CASSANDRA-7337](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7337) which was fixed in C* 2.0.9.

The latest DataStax Enterprise is now on 2.0.11. If you are seeing this issue ==> Upgrade!

Comment: Good find!  If I had a dollar for every time I told someone here that upgrading Cassandra was their best plan, I wouldn't have to work.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd code snippet doesn't look right to me (there's no constructor taking a string or you've missed the prepared statement).

Can you try instead the following:

```
String update = "Update mykeyspace.mytable set record_version = ? where id = ? if record_version = ?";
PreparedStatement pStmt = session.prepare(update);
BatchStatement batch = new BatchStatement();
batch.add(pStmt.bind(newVersion, id, recordVersion));

Row row = session.execute(batch).one();
if (! row.getBool("[applied]")) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Optimistic Lock Failure!");
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry--the instantiation of the prepared statement wasn't clear because it was created as a global member and I failed to demonstrate this in my sample code.  Basically my original code did precisely what you recommended except it it also incorporated a BoundStatement wrapper around the PreparedStatement.  I tried your suggestion with a simple prepared statement (no BoundStatement) but observed the same problem.